# Finding max values at a point given a list of ranges

Tags: algorithms, sorting, intervals, lists

In coding competitions I usually see problems that involve dealing with values in given ranges. A typical example is, given a list of 3-tuples defined as so

```
3-tuple = (Left bound of interval, Right bound of interval, Value on this interval)
```

Now these intervals can be overlapping so we can have something like

```
list = [(0, 2, 10), (1, 4, 15)]
```

Where 10 is the max value between 0 and 1, and then 15 is the max value from 1 to 4.

So with these types of problems, what is the appropriate way to approach them to try and find the maximum value at each point? Naively we could do something like:

- For each index `a`
- Loop through all our 3-tuples and for each tuple, if `a` falls within its range, check that range's value and see if it is larger than what we have seen before
- Update the max value for index `a` as needed

Now this is an O(k*n), where k is the number of points and n is the length of the list. I was curious if there was a better way to approach this problem, and in general problems which give list of intervals.

Comment: Please look at Segment Tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree